# .load jquery event after previous .load event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to render a user submitted picture at the submitted_picture div after successful Ajax call. My controller and code works but my issue is that I cannot figure out how to add another picture without rendering on top of the previous(example: second picture will load where the previous one was). I am using the ruby on rails framework and coffee script but I can translate jQuery syntax, I just need an idea how to solve this.

```
<div id="submitted_picture"></div>  

($ '#new_picture').on 'ajax:success', (evt, data, status, xhr) =>
  ($ "#submitted_picture").load "/picture/#{xhr.responseJSON.id}/load_div"
```

Comment: You want to replace the content of `#submitted_picture`? Or add another `<img>` to it? Or something else?

Comment: Add another one to it, so I have a list of pictures. Submit one it gets rendered, post another one, it gets rendered after it not on top of it.

Comment: The jquery load function, just re-renders the picture in the same spot doing exactly what you dont want to do. You need to rerender the whole html in a container with all the pics and send it down. Or use the append method. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RoR, I'd look into using paritals for AJAX calls, its a pretty common pattern. For example, if you have a partial of `_pictures.html.erb` that looks like this:

```
<% @pictures.each do |pic| %>
  <div id="submitted_picture"><img src="#{pic}"/></div>
<%end%>
```

then what you can do is the following in your controller:

```
html = render_to_string(partial: 'pictures')
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: {html: html} }
end
```

Then grab the response in your coffeescript like this:

```
$.post 'my/url',
  (data) ->
    $('#picture-container').html(data.html)
```

Now you've effectively submitted a request and used the updated part of the HTML instead of trying to add to it. You've replaced the entire picture container with the updated html instead of adding to it. This is IMO a better way of doing this if you're using AJAX to update things.